# remove columns and replace title in different column when merging csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I have merged two seperate csv files using pd.merge. The result looks like this:
[image: merged csv]

Basically I want to remove the region column in each case and replace it to the name of the column, my desired result looks like this:

[image: desired result]

My current code for merging the csv files and moving the settlement date to the left is this:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv("QLD.csv") 
data2 = pd.read_csv("VIC.csv")
result = pd.merge(data1[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], data2[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], on='SETTLEMENTDATE')
cols = result.columns.tolist()
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('SETTLEMENTDATE')))
result = result.reindex(columns= cols)
result.to_csv("masterfile.csv", index=False)
```

My question is how could I modify my code to achieve my desired result?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/george/Desktop/collate/merge pdf.py", line 9, in <module>
    result.columns=['SETTLEMENTDATE','QLD DEMAND','QLD RRP','VLC DEMAND','VLC RRP']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4389, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 646, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3323, in set_axis
    'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 5 elements
```

Edit1:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv("QLD.csv") 
data2 = pd.read_csv("VIC.csv")
result = pd.merge(data1[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], data2[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], on='SETTLEMENTDATE')
cols = result.columns.tolist()
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('SETTLEMENTDATE')))
result = result.reindex(columns= cols)
result = result.drop(result.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)
result = result.rename(columns={'SETTLEMENTDATE': 'SETTLEMENTDATE', 'TOTALDEMAND_x': 
                    'QLD DEMAND','RRP_x':'QLD RRP','TOTALDEMAND_x':'VIC DEMAND','RRP_y':'VIC RRP'})
result.to_csv("masterfile.csv", index=False)
```

Excel file:

[image: excel file]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you merge your dataframes you could remove a column using `drop`. And then jsut use `rename` to rename the columns.

```
result = result.drop(result.columns[[1, 4]], axis=1)  # df.columns is zero-based pd.Index 
result = result.rename(columns={'SETTLEMENTDATE': 'SETTLEMENTDATE', 'TOTALDEMAND_x': 
                    'QLD DEMAND','RRP_x':'QLD RRP','TOTALDEMAND_y':'VIC DEMAND','RRP_y':'VIC RRP'})
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, but it stuffs up somewhere? I edited my post to show you this?

Comment: @newtoR I edited my post. Sorry, Instead of `TOTALDEMAND_y` I have written it as `TOTALDEMAND_x`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the region columns and include the `result.columns=['col1','col2',....]` in your code like this to rename the columns.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data1 = pd.read_csv("QLD.csv") 
    data2 = pd.read_csv("VIC.csv")
    result = pd.merge(data1[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], data2[['REGION', 'TOTALDEMAND', 'RRP','SETTLEMENTDATE']], on='SETTLEMENTDATE')
    cols = result.columns.tolist()
    cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index('SETTLEMENTDATE')))
    result = result.reindex(columns= cols)
    result = result[result.columns.drop('REGION_x','REGION_y')]
    result.columns=['SETTLEMENTDATE','QLD DEMAND','QLD RRP','VLC DEMAND','VLC RRP']
    result.to_csv("masterfile.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: When I run your code I receive an error, error is now in my original post(I edited it)